# Remove text from a node but not descendant nodes

Tags: java, html, dom, domparser

I have an XML with HTML data, and trying to remove free text lying inside 'Body' tag without removing the child 'DIV' tag contents. Till now I have used removeChild(), which also removed everything else inside BODY.
Then tried getting the NODE_TYPE==3 for filtering and removing only text content, but I am getting NODE_TYPE==1 when running it.

When using setTextContent(), it is setting the whole tag data to my input string.

This is what my XML Looks like :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<HTML>
    <HEAD>
        <META content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type"/>
    </HEAD>
    <BODY>
        <DIV class="WordSection1">
        <P>Enter Text here</P> <P>COMPLETED</P>
        </DIV>
    TEXT I WANT TO REMOVE
    </BODY>
</HTML>
```

After changes, I need output like this :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<HTML>
    <HEAD>
        <META content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type"/>
    </HEAD>
    <BODY>
        <DIV class="WordSection1">
        <P>Enter Text here</P> <P>COMPLETED</P>
        </DIV>

    </BODY>
</HTML>
```

Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 0):

I understand you're using the 'old' org.w3c.dom library that comes with Java. Assuming you read the document content into a Document `doc`, you could do:

```
Node textNode = doc.getDocumentElement().getLastChild().getPreviousSibling().getLastChild();
doc.getDocumentElement().getLastChild().getPreviousSibling().removeChild(textNode);
```

...although this isn't quite robust with regards to changes to the input XML.

You might want to try a different XML API (e.g. JDom). The old one often doesn't make your life very easy.